# Communication between program running on Standalone VM and Browser based App

Tags: dart, send-port

If a communication mechanism has to be established between a stand-alone Dart VM and browser based application on the same machine, how can this be achieved in DART.

The dart:io library does not work in browser-based applications.

Hence, using SendPort/ReceivePort cannot be used.

Comment: HTTP. i.e. start a web server in the standalone VM, and use HttpRequest to call it from the browser. If you want full two way communication you can use websockets.

Comment: SendPort/ReceivePort is for communication between isolates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could:

- use WebSockets on the Browser side and
- use a (Server)Socket on the stand-alone dart VM to listen for incoming websockets.

Regards,
Robert

**EDIT**

A long time ago I wrote a nodejs server side implementation of a websocket-server - maybe this helps you do setup the server side if you decide to use websockets:

https://github.com/roberthartung/kit_websocket